Distribution of coefficients of characteristic polynomial of a random matrix
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a random matrix whose coefficients $a_{ij}$ are uniformly distributed in $[-1, 1]$. Writing its characteristic polynomial as
$$ p_A(x) = \det(A-xI) = \sum_k b_k x^k \,, $$
what is the distribution of each $b_k$ (except for $b_n = 1$)? I would for instance imagine that $b_0 = (-1)^n \det(A)$ and $b_{n-1} = -\text{Tr}(A)$ are also uniformly distributed, but I'm not sure where to begin.

"I'm not sure where to begin". Fix a small size, i.e., work with for example both cases, either $4 \times 4$ and/or $5 \times 5$ matrices (it is good to have an idea on both the even and odd cases). Make a million of  computer simulations, with histogram representations for the different coefficients. Then you will have an idea of the distribution of each one and be able to build conjectures.

@Jean Marie Thank you for the tip -- will try it out & keep the post updated asap!
